# Rails g migration goes new line and does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, rails-generate

```
$ rails generate migration add_password_digest_to_users password_digest:string
```

Have to add password_digest to user but rails generate comand doesn't work. It just pretending to work but seems like it will lasts forever. No errors or backtrace were returned, just new line.

Comment: So it doesn't finish its job and just freezes instead, right?

Comment: What happens if you add the option `--trace`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is spring problem. This problem appears due to interrupting `$ rails generate` command.

To solve it you should stop all spring processes:

```
$ spring stop
```

And then:

```
$ rails generate
```

You can find more details here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13381